# Get Features Extraction for offline character recognition using HMM

Tags: matlab, character, feature-extraction, handwriting-recognition

I'm implementing an character recognition system with Hidden Markov Model(HMM). I have used skeleton to extract features of image. And I thought to use HMM for training images.

My question is how I can give those features to HMM? I got to know that I have to save those features into a file and then that file should feed to the HMM.

Can someone please help me? I am stuck here for two months. Still, I couldn't find the solution for this.

Appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing by and just saw this question.

Maybe you looked somewhere because your question is almost a month ago.

You give the features to HMM by clustering your data, you can use k-means, or you can use windows with lengths. If you use k-means, you will obtain the centers, you can use the centers to obtain the features, after this you need to crossfold validation to see if it really learns the features you labeled. Also K-means gives you the states and the initial transition probabilities.

Hope this helps you